# r summarize data by specific date for each year

Tags: r, time, series

I have a daily precipitation data for 50 years:

| year | month | day | daily_prec | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1960 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1960-01-01 |
| 1960 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1960-02-01 |

For each year, I want to get a sum of precipitation for some specific days of vegetation season in a new df like for example: from 1975-05-22 to 1975-07-15, from 1976-05-22 to 1976-06-15 etc.

| year | start | end | sum | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 1975-22-05 | 1975-15-07 | 5 | 3 |
| 1976 | 1976-22-05 | 1976-15-07 | 2 | 1 |

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Where are the start and end dates coming from? Do you have are those predefined in a vector or something?

Comment: How is the precipitation data organised? Is it one long vector with dates? Or something else?

Comment: start and end date coming from date column: 
df$date:Date, format: "1901-01-01"
for precipitation: 
 df$daily_prec : chr  "" "" "1.7" ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that filters the daily precipitation dataframe for the period delimited by the start and end dates, and apply that rowwise. In this example the dataframe is separate, but you can use the same da

```
daily_prec_df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("1960-01-01"), as.Date("1965-01-01"), by=1)
)

library(lubridate)
daily_prec_df <- daily_prec_df %>%
    mutate(
    year = year(date),
    month = month(date),
    day = day(date),
    daily_prec = sample(1:10, replace = T, size = nrow(daily_prec_df))
)

get_period_aggregates <- function(start, end) {
    res_df <- daily_prec_df %>%
    filter(date >= start, date <= end) %>%
    summarize(sum = sum(daily_prec), mean=mean(daily_prec))
}

aggregate_df <- data.frame(
  year = c(1961, 1962),
  start = as.Date(c("1961-05-22", "1962-05-22")),
  end = as.Date(c("1961-06-22", "1962-06-22"))
)

aggregate_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    sum = get_period_aggregates(start, end)$sum, 
    mean = get_period_aggregates(start, end)$mean
  )

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Rowwise: 
   year start      end          sum  mean
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <int> <dbl>
1  1961 1961-05-22 1961-06-22   169  5.28
2  1962 1962-05-22 1962-06-22   206  6.44
```

Answer (score 1):

You could paste an arbitrary year (like the current as shown here) to day-month and subset the data until `"YYYY-07-15"` using `<=`, then `aggregate()`.

```
u <- as.POSIXct(substring(as.character(dat$date), 6), '%m-%d', tz='UTC') <= 
  as.POSIXct(paste0(strftime(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-07-15'), tz='UTC')

aggregate(prec ~ year, dat[u, ], function(x) c(sum=sum(x), mean=mean(x)))
#   year    prec.sum   prec.mean
# 1   75 1014.000000    5.173469
# 2   76  926.000000    4.724490
# 3   77  968.000000    4.938776
```

*Check:*

```
sum(dat[dat$date <= as.Date('1975-07-15'), 'prec'])
# [1] 1014

mean(dat[dat$date <= as.Date('1975-07-15'), 'prec'])
# [1] 5.173469
```

**Note:** In `aggregate()`, instead of `prec ~ year` you also could use `prec ~ substr(dat$date, 1, 4)`, so you even would not need to break the date into its individual components beforehand.

### Edit

Four a time window, you consequently could do this:

```
u1 <- as.POSIXct(substring(as.character(dat$date), 6), '%m-%d', tz='UTC')
u <- u1 <= as.POSIXct(paste0(strftime(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-07-15'), tz='UTC') &
  u1 >= as.POSIXct(paste0(strftime(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-06-15'), tz='UTC')

aggregate(prec ~ year, dat[u, ], function(x) c(sum=sum(x), mean=mean(x)))
#   year   prec.sum  prec.mean
# 1   75 141.000000   4.548387
# 2   76 146.000000   4.709677
# 3   77 155.000000   5.000000
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1826, 1827, 1828, 1829, 1830, 
1831, 1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 
1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 
1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 
1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 
1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 
1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 
1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 
1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 
1919, 1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 
1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 
1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 
1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 
1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 
1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 
1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 
2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 
2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2049, 2050, 
2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 
2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069, 2070, 2071, 2072, 
2073, 2074, 2075, 2076, 2077, 2078, 2079, 2080, 2081, 2082, 2083, 
2084, 2085, 2086, 2087, 2088, 2089, 2090, 2091, 2092, 2093, 2094, 
2095, 2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, 
2106, 2107, 2108, 2109, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2114, 2115, 2116, 
2117, 2118, 2119, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2123, 2124, 2125, 2126, 2127, 
2128, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2134, 2135, 2136, 2137, 2138, 
2139, 2140, 2141, 2142, 2143, 2144, 2145, 2146, 2147, 2148, 2149, 
2150, 2151, 2152, 2153, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2158, 2159, 2160, 
2161, 2162, 2163, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2168, 2169, 2170, 2171, 
2172, 2173, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 2180, 2181, 2182, 
2183, 2184, 2185, 2186, 2187, 2188, 2189, 2190, 2191, 2192, 2193, 
2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2203, 2204, 
2205, 2206, 2207, 2208, 2209, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2215, 
2216, 2217, 2218, 2219, 2220, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2224, 2225, 2226, 
2227, 2228, 2229, 2230, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2234, 2235, 2236, 2237, 
2238, 2239, 2240, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 
2249, 2250, 2251, 2252, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 
2260, 2261, 2262, 2263, 2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 
2271, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2281, 
2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 
2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 
2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 
2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2325, 
2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 
2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347, 
2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 
2359, 2360, 2361, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 
2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2375, 2376, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 
2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 
2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2402, 
2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 
2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 
2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2433, 2434, 2435, 
2436, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2440, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2446, 
2447, 2448, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2455, 2456, 2457, 
2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 
2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 
2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 
2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 
2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 
2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 
2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2528, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2532, 2533, 2534, 
2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544, 2545, 
2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2556, 
2557, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 
2568, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 
2579, 2580, 2581, 2582, 2583, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589, 
2590, 2591, 2592, 2593, 2594, 2595, 2596, 2597, 2598, 2599, 2600, 
2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2607, 2608, 2609, 2610, 2611, 
2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2618, 2619, 2620, 2621, 2622, 
2623, 2624, 2625, 2626, 2627, 2628, 2629, 2630, 2631, 2632, 2633, 
2634, 2635, 2636, 2637, 2638, 2639, 2640, 2641, 2642, 2643, 2644, 
2645, 2646, 2647, 2648, 2649, 2650, 2651, 2652, 2653, 2654, 2655, 
2656, 2657, 2658, 2659, 2660, 2661, 2662, 2663, 2664, 2665, 2666, 
2667, 2668, 2669, 2670, 2671, 2672, 2673, 2674, 2675, 2676, 2677, 
2678, 2679, 2680, 2681, 2682, 2683, 2684, 2685, 2686, 2687, 2688, 
2689, 2690, 2691, 2692, 2693, 2694, 2695, 2696, 2697, 2698, 2699, 
2700, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2704, 2705, 2706, 2707, 2708, 2709, 2710, 
2711, 2712, 2713, 2714, 2715, 2716, 2717, 2718, 2719, 2720, 2721, 
2722, 2723, 2724, 2725, 2726, 2727, 2728, 2729, 2730, 2731, 2732, 
2733, 2734, 2735, 2736, 2737, 2738, 2739, 2740, 2741, 2742, 2743, 
2744, 2745, 2746, 2747, 2748, 2749, 2750, 2751, 2752, 2753, 2754, 
2755, 2756, 2757, 2758, 2759, 2760, 2761, 2762, 2763, 2764, 2765, 
2766, 2767, 2768, 2769, 2770, 2771, 2772, 2773, 2774, 2775, 2776, 
2777, 2778, 2779, 2780, 2781, 2782, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2787, 
2788, 2789, 2790, 2791, 2792, 2793, 2794, 2795, 2796, 2797, 2798, 
2799, 2800, 2801, 2802, 2803, 2804, 2805, 2806, 2807, 2808, 2809, 
2810, 2811, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2816, 2817, 2818, 2819, 2820, 
2821, 2822, 2823, 2824, 2825, 2826, 2827, 2828, 2829, 2830, 2831, 
2832, 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836, 2837, 2838, 2839, 2840, 2841, 2842, 
2843, 2844, 2845, 2846, 2847, 2848, 2849, 2850, 2851, 2852, 2853, 
2854, 2855, 2856, 2857, 2858, 2859, 2860, 2861, 2862, 2863, 2864, 
2865, 2866, 2867, 2868, 2869, 2870, 2871, 2872, 2873, 2874, 2875, 
2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 2881, 2882, 2883, 2884, 2885, 2886, 
2887, 2888, 2889, 2890, 2891, 2892, 2893, 2894, 2895, 2896, 2897, 
2898, 2899, 2900, 2901, 2902, 2903, 2904, 2905, 2906, 2907, 2908, 
2909, 2910, 2911, 2912, 2913, 2914, 2915, 2916, 2917, 2918, 2919, 
2920, 2921), class = "Date"), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12), day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L), year = c(75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L), prec = c(9, 9, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 1, 7, 7, 5, 7, 
9, 3, 5, 9, 10, 1, 5, 6, 9, 1, 10, 9, 1, 5, 4, 9, 4, 8, 7, 8, 
4, 7, 0, 8, 0, 2, 9, 6, 4, 4, 0, 10, 4, 10, 9, 6, 10, 6, 3, 3, 
4, 8, 0, 7, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 8, 6, 8, 2, 3, 8, 7, 2, 0, 1, 
2, 5, 2, 7, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 7, 0, 2, 
9, 9, 7, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4, 9, 10, 7, 7, 5, 0, 6, 8, 8, 
5, 5, 5, 0, 4, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 9, 10, 2, 7, 9, 6, 6, 
9, 9, 6, 8, 1, 8, 6, 1, 1, 5, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 3, 1, 7, 3, 8, 4, 
7, 8, 2, 0, 1, 7, 9, 6, 6, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
1, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
5, 1, 7, 7, 9, 5, 9, 4, 2, 4, 10, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 
6, 4, 5, 9, 5, 2, 5, 10, 3, 8, 3, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 10, 8, 
1, 9, 6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5, 0, 8, 1, 
5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 9, 2, 9, 9, 1, 8, 5, 1, 9, 3, 3, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 0, 2, 10, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 7, 3, 4, 3, 1, 8, 6, 
1, 0, 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 9, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 10, 5, 1, 2, 9, 3, 7, 
9, 10, 4, 4, 1, 3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 7, 5, 5, 3, 
8, 3, 4, 1, 8, 4, 0, 0, 10, 4, 8, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 5, 7, 10, 
5, 5, 6, 7, 3, 10, 6, 6, 6, 9, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8, 1, 7, 10, 2, 1, 
1, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8, 1, 10, 2, 1, 9, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 10, 9, 
6, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4, 9, 1, 10, 3, 1, 4, 1, 6, 2, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 
4, 1, 1, 5, 10, 8, 5, 1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 1, 9, 0, 4, 2, 
1, 5, 7, 9, 4, 9, 3, 5, 1, 8, 7, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 7, 9, 
8, 4, 1, 8, 1, 1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 9, 3, 0, 9, 10, 5, 5, 6, 9, 2, 
8, 2, 6, 8, 1, 9, 5, 9, 2, 1, 0, 10, 5, 8, 4, 5, 2, 8, 3, 2, 
0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 
8, 9, 8, 1, 6, 7, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 5, 5, 2, 7, 
10, 5, 2, 6, 8, 7, 2, 3, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 9, 8, 8, 
2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 8, 6, 2, 10, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6, 2, 
9, 7, 6, 2, 5, 10, 10, 5, 7, 3, 8, 4, 10, 8, 5, 5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 
3, 8, 3, 5, 5, 8, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 
2, 7, 2, 7, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 1, 5, 9, 7, 3, 1, 6, 
8, 5, 7, 5, 4, 10, 9, 2, 10, 9, 7, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 3, 8, 9, 3, 
8, 2, 8, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 8, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 9, 7, 10, 
3, 8, 1, 1, 7, 5, 6, 1, 9, 8, 0, 7, 5, 9, 9, 5, 8, 5, 2, 7, 8, 
7, 2, 3, 3, 6, 9, 9, 4, 7, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 1, 4, 3, 8, 
4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 10, 10, 9, 1, 5, 3, 7, 6, 9, 9, 6, 5, 9, 9, 4, 
1, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 1, 10, 9, 10, 7, 1, 0, 7, 7, 
9, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 7, 0, 9, 9, 8, 10, 6, 7, 4, 1, 7, 1, 
3, 6, 4, 1, 9, 4, 7, 0, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 1, 9, 9, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 
2, 3, 5, 2, 9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 9, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 4, 0, 0, 10, 2, 
0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 6, 6, 3, 7, 9, 0, 8, 8, 1, 6, 5, 1, 3, 4, 
8, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6, 9, 4, 9, 10, 7, 3, 2, 3, 9, 1, 2, 
5, 3, 8, 9, 0, 8, 4, 7, 1, 5, 9, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 9, 2, 2, 1, 8, 
8, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 9, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 0, 4, 0, 6, 9, 3, 2, 5, 1, 
4, 3, 9, 9, 8, 8, 10, 6, 2, 1, 8, 10, 10, 1, 6, 9, 1, 4, 2, 4, 
5, 10, 9, 9, 8, 1, 0, 3, 2, 8, 5, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 0, 7, 6, 1, 
3, 4, 3, 7, 4, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7, 4, 7, 0, 8, 1, 9, 1, 2, 8, 2, 4, 
4, 6, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 4, 0, 5, 8, 5, 2, 9, 1, 3, 9, 8, 1, 
8, 9, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 0, 8, 1, 8, 5, 5, 0, 6, 7, 2, 8, 4, 6, 2, 
2, 2, 8, 1, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 10, 9, 10, 2, 0, 
1, 4, 5, 9, 6, 5, 1, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 6, 8, 10, 0, 8, 2, 1, 
7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 1, 1, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 6, 0, 5, 9, 
2, 7, 9, 0, 1, 1, 4, 10, 4, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 7, 0, 9, 0, 8, 5, 
3, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -1096L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How to modify first 2 lines to get:

`sum(dat[dat$date <= as.Date('1975-07-15')&dat$date>=as.Date('1975-06-15'), 'prec'])`
`# [1] 141`

`mean(dat[dat$date <= as.Date('1975-07-15')&dat$date>=as.Date('1975-06-15'), 'prec'])`
`# [1] 4.548387`

Comment: @MarcinKoprowski See my edit, please.